# Rails/Ransack: eq_all array of ids

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ransack

```
@array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I have the following input

```
= f.input :organism_id_eq_all, collection: @array
```

But it doesn't work in ransack, I get the following sql:

```
SELECT ... WHERE `organism_id` IN (0)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `_in` instead of `_eq_all`

```
= f.input :organism_id_in, collection: @array
```

The rendered HTML will generate an array of selected IDs when POSTed.